# map into a hashmap of input to output? Does this function exist?

Tags: clojure

I have a higher-order `map`-like function that returns a hashmap representing the application (input to output) of the function.

```
(defn map-application [f coll] (into {} (map #(vector % (f %)) coll)))
```

To be used thus:

```
(map-application str [1 2 3 4 5])
{1 "1", 2 "2", 3 "3", 4 "4", 5 "5"}

(map-application (partial * 10) [1 2 3 4 5])
{1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40, 5 50}
```

Does this function already exist, or does this pattern have a recognised name?

I know it's only a one-liner, but looking at the constellation of related functions in `clojure.core`, this looks like the kind of thing that already exists.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the term you are looking for is `transducer`. 
https://clojure.org/reference/transducers

in fact the transducing variant would look almost like yours (the key difference is that `coll` argument is passed to `into` function not `map`), but it does it's job without any intermediate collections:

```
user> (defn into-map [f coll]
        (into {} (map (juxt identity f)) coll))
#'user/into-map
user> (into-map inc [1 2 3])
;;=> {1 2, 2 3, 3 4}
```

this can also be done with the simple reduction, though it requires a bit more manual work:

```
user> (defn map-into-2 [f coll]
        (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (f %2)) {} coll))
#'user/map-into-2
user> (map-into-2 inc [1 2 3])
;;=> {1 2, 2 3, 3 4}
```

Comment: Thanks! `juxt` is a lot nicer than that the messy vector stuff. And using a transducer is also an improvement. However, my question was about the top-level function (essentially the `into {}` part, but I do get that using a transducer rather than a tuple seq with `into` is a different usage).

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is easily handled by the built-in `zipmap` function:

```
(defn map-application
  [f coll]
  (zipmap coll (map f coll)))

(map-application (partial * 10) [1 2 3 4 5])
=> {1 10, 2 20, 3 30, 4 40, 5 50}
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, thanks. However, my question was about the top-level function.